# Java PMD CommentSize error for header comments

Tags: java, comments, pmd

I have a Java file that has 40 lines of comments at the beginning of the source code to describe basic algorithm implemented in it, like this:

```
/**
 * Detailed descriptions
 * ...
   ... < total 40 lines of comments > ...
 */
```

However PMD emits an "CommentSize" error like this:

```
<violation beginline="1" endline="40" begincolumn="1" endcolumn="2"
 rule="CommentSize" ruleset="Comments"
 package="..." 
 externalInfoUrl="https://pmd.github.io/pmd-5.4.0/pmd-java/rules/java/comments.html#CommentSize"
 priority="3">
    Comment is too large: Too many lines
</violation>
```

From detailed [explanation here](https://pmd.github.io/pmd-5.4.0/pmd-java/rules/java/comments.html#CommentSize) I found:

> Determines whether the dimensions of ***non-header*** comments found are
>   within the specified limits.

To my understanding this rule applys only on ***non-header*** comments and my comments at the top of source should not trigger this error, so my question is: do I misunderstand what **non-header** comments are or there's a implementation problem in PMD?

Comment: This seems like a bug on PMD. You should probably report it at https://github.com/pmd/pmd/issues

Answer (score 0):

Did you configure the rule?  There's a [parameter](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/snapshot/pmd-java/rules/java/comments.html) named headerCommentRequirement that you can configure. I think you need to set it to ignored.